# Cant validate JSON when using different language. Error invalid characters found

Tags: json

First time im trying to create a JSON file,
Im trying to create a JSON file with different language other than English , but when i try to validate, it show **Error Invalid characters found**.

i tried this

```
    {
            "data": [
    
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": "Oru Velli Thaaram Vaana Veedhiyil",
                    "lyrics": "ഒരു വെള്ളിത്താരം വനവീഥിയിൽ തെളിയവേ
    കുളിരീറൻ കാറ്റും കുഞ്ഞുതരാട്ട് മൂളവേ
    ഇരുളിനലകൾ മൂടും ധരയിതിലൊരു ദീപം
    കദനഭാരമെല്ലാം നീക്കിടുന്ന സ്നേഹം
    പിറന്നു മണ്ണിലുഷസ്സിൻ ശോഭ പോലെ
              (ഒരു വെള്ളിത്താരം…
    
    മരുഭൂവിൽ അലയുമ്പോൾ ആ താരം മുൻപേ
    മറയാതെ രാജക്കൾക്കതുമാർഗമായി
    മരുഭൂവിൽ അലയുമ്പോൾ ആ താരം മുൻപേ
    മറയാതെ രാജക്കൾക്കതുമാർഗമായി
    പുൽക്കൂടും തേടിത്തേടി ബെത്ലഹേമിലവരണയുമ്പോൾ
    ഗീതങ്ങൾ പാടിപ്പാടി വാനദൂതരും അണയുന്നൂ
    തിരുസുതനെ കാണുംനേരം പാടുന്നു ഗ്ലോറിയ …
              (ഒരു വെള്ളിത്താരം…
    ശാരോനിൻ താഴ്വാരം തഴുകുന്ന കാറ്റെ
    വരുമോ എൻ നാഥൻറെ അരികിൽ  നീ മെല്ലെ
    ശാരോനിൻ താഴ്വാരം തഴുകുന്ന കാറ്റെ
    വരുമോ എൻ നാഥൻറെ അരികിൽ  നീ മെല്ലെ
    തഴുകൂ നിൻ വിരലാൽ നെറുകിൽ  സ്നേഹനാഥനെ ആലോലം
    പാടൂ നൽ  ശ്രുതിയാൽ  കാതിൽ സാന്ദ്രമാനന്ദ സംഗീതം
    ഈ രാവിൽ പാരാകെ പാടുന്നു ഗ്ലോറിയ
             (ഒരു വെള്ളിത്താരം…",
                   
                
                },
                 {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "Pukootil Vannu Jaathanayi",
                    "lyrics": "പുൽക്കൂട്ടിൽ വന്നു ജാതനായി
    നക്ഷത്രം ഇന്ന് മിന്നി നിന്നു
    ക്രിസ്മസ് രാവിൻറെ ഗാനമായി
    വിണ്ണിൽ ആനന്ദമേളമായി താരകം ദീപമായ്
    കൺകളിൽ തിളങ്ങി നിന്നു (2 )
    
    ദൂതരാ വീണകൾ മീട്ടിടുന്നിതാ
    ലോകരാ കീർത്തനം കേട്ടിടുന്നിതാ
    ദേവദാരു പൂത്തു പാതിരാവു പെയ്തു
    മഞ്ഞുതുള്ളി വീണവീഥി മിന്നിടുന്നു
            ( പുൽക്കൂട്ടിൽ)
    
    വിദ്വരോ കാഴ്ചകൾ നല്കിടുന്നിതാ
    വിന്നതിൽ നോക്കി സംപ്രീതരായിതാ
    കീറ്റുശീല തന്നിൽ ദിവ്യശോഭ കണ്ടു
    ആട്ടിടയരെത്തി ആർത്തു പാടിടുന്നു
            ( പുൽക്കൂട്ടിൽ)",
                 
                
                }
]
}
```

Error shows as INVALID JSON , Invalid characters found.
[image: Error Screenshot]

please help me to resolve this problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem Coming from**

```
"lyrics": "ഒരു വെള്ളിത്താരം വനവീഥിയിൽ തെളിയവേ
```

**Error Type**

```
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

**Reason**

1. **Line breaks inside your string** . Encode with `\n` .A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters .

Comment: thank u so much bro. i was so confused and thought this was due the problem of language i used.